# css display: online; not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, inline

if you take a look at this link http://northshorewebdesign.net/walkboston/index.html there's a set of 4 icons for navigation near the bottom left. You'll notice that rather than sitting horizontally, they're diagonal - not what I want. In FF, Chrom, IE9 the icons line up horizontally the way they should. Can someone tell me why the go diagonally in IE7?
I have set display: inline; and float: left;

Answer (score 2):

You should set them **display:block** and set a **width** for each of them, then the **float:left** will work as you wish.

Comment: +1 but don't forget to add an element with clear: both; after the icons, otherwise the footer is gonna end up on top.

Comment: I actually had to float each li like: `ul#icon-links li { float:left; }`